# How to establish a many to many relationship in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to build a simple app where users can follow other users so, I have a table "Users" that has all the user's info, and since a user can follow many users and that user can have many followers we get a Many-to-Many relationship, so I created a linking table. Here's my code:
[image]

As you can see the "UsersFollowing" table has composite Primary Key that is build from the Foreign Keys taken from the "User" table (user, and who is following).

Now I want to get the following: **"Given a user id return all the users that follows".**

I'm new in SQLAlchemy and I don't know how to get the result.

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as images - images are not accessible, not searchable and not copy-and-pastable for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the SQLAlchemy ORM, you should be able to get the users by issuing a join and filtering:

```
db_session.query(User)\
    .join(UsersFollowing, User.id == UsersFollowing.user_following_id)\
    .filter(UsersFollowing.user_id == <userid>)
```